# Forcing gaps between words in a Marpa grammar

Tags: perl, parsing, marpa

I'm trying to set up a grammar that requires that `[\w]` characters cannot appear directly adjacent to each other if they are not in the same lexeme. That is, words must be separated from each other by a space or punctuation.

Consider the following grammar:

```
use Marpa::R2; use Data::Dump;

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({source  => \<<'END_OF_GRAMMAR'});

:start ::= Rule
Rule ::= '9' 'september'

:discard ~ whitespace
whitespace ~ [\s]+

END_OF_GRAMMAR

my $recce = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({grammar => $grammar});
dd $recce->read(\'9september');
```

This parses successfully.  Now I want to change the grammar to force a separation between `9` and `september`.  I thought of doing this by introducing an unused lexeme that matches `[\w]+`:

```
use Marpa::R2; use Data::Dump;

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({source  => \<<'END_OF_GRAMMAR'});

:start ::= Rule
Rule ::= '9' 'september'

:discard ~ whitespace
whitespace ~ [\s]+

word ~ [\w]+      ### <== Add unused lexeme to match joined keywords
END_OF_GRAMMAR

my $recce = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({grammar => $grammar});
dd $recce->read(\'9september');
```

Unfortunately, this grammar fails with:

```
A lexeme is not accessible from the start symbol: word
Marpa::R2 exception at marpa.pl line 3.
```

Although this can be resolved by using a `lexeme default` statement:

```
use Marpa::R2; use Data::Dump;

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({source  => \<<'END_OF_GRAMMAR'});
lexeme default = action => [value]  ### <== Fix exception by adding lexeme default statement

:start ::= Rule
Rule ::= '9' 'september'

:discard ~ whitespace
whitespace ~ [\s]+

word ~ [\w]+
END_OF_GRAMMAR

my $recce = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({grammar => $grammar});
dd $recce->read(\'9september');
```

This results in the following output:

```
Inaccessible symbol: word
Error in SLIF parse: No lexemes accepted at line 1, column 1
* String before error: 
* The error was at line 1, column 1, and at character 0x0039 '9', ...
* here: 9september
Marpa::R2 exception at marpa.pl line 16.
```

That is, the parse has failed due to the fact that there is no gap between `9` and `september` which is exactly what I want to happen.  The only fly in the ointment is that there is an annoying `Inaccessible symbol: word` message on STDERR because the `word` lexeme is not used in the actual grammar.

I see that in `Marpa::R2::Grammar` I could have declared `word` as `inaccessible_ok` in the constructor options but I can't do that in `Marpa::R2::Scanless`.

I also could have done something like the following:

```
Rule ::= nine september
nine ~ word
september ~ word
```

then used a `pause` to use custom code to examine the actual lexeme value and return the appropriate lexeme depending on the value.

What is the best way to construct a grammar that uses keywords or numbers and words but will disallow adjacent lexemes to be run together without white space or punctuation separating them?

Comment: In P::RD, I'd do `/\w+/ { $item[0] eq 'keyword' }`. There's also `/9\b/`

Answer (score 4):

Well, the obvious solution is to require some whitespace in between (on the G1 level). When we use the following grammar

```
:default ::= action => ::array

:start ::= Rule
Rule ::= '9' (Ws) 'september'

Ws ::= [\s]+

:discard ~ whitespace
whitespace ~ [\s]+
```

then `9september` fails, but `9 september` is parsed. Important points to note:

- Lexemes can be both discarded and required, when they are both a longest token. This is why the `:discard` and `Ws` rule don't interfere with each other. Marpa doesn't mind this kind of “ambiguity”.
- The `Ws` rule is enclosed in parens, which discards the value – to keep the resulting parse tree clean.
- You do not usually want to use tricks like phantom lexemes to misguide the parser. That way lies breakage.
- When every bit of whitespace is important, you might want to get rid of `:discard ~ whitespace`. This is meant to be used e.g. for C-like languages where whitespace traditionally does not matter.

Comment: Yes, requiring whitespace in between is obvious, and yet, I didn't think of it! I wonder if it will extend to the general case in a bigger grammar.